# Pointer operations, memory scanning

Tags: c, pointers

In following code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc,char** argv)
{
     char *str = "Hello world";
     char *p = &argc+1;
     printf("%i \n",(&argc+1));         
     printf("%i \n",*(&argc+1));
     printf("%i \n",&str);             
     printf("%i \n",*str);
     printf("%i \n",p);                 
     printf("%i \n",*p);
     return 0;
 }
```

The output is:

```
-541685632
4196028
-541685632
72
-541685632
-68
```

My question is, since they're all pointing to the same address how come what they are pointing to is not the same value;

Comment: Note: you should be using `%p` to display pointer values.

Comment: More importantly, `(&argc+1)` is not a valid way to obtain `argv`.  Your program invokes undefined behaviour.  If you want to understand what's happening, take a look at the resulting assembler.  But that won't tell you anything about the behaviour of C in general.

Comment: Actually for me `(&argc+1)` resulting in crash :-O

Comment: @neagoegab: Like `%i`, but for pointers.  http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf

Comment: @neag You can look it up in the docs

Comment: (&argc+1) just happens to be the same as (&str)

Comment: @neagoegab: The actual output format is implementation-defined, but `%p` is the only well-defined way to display a pointer.

Answer (score 2):

Of course this is all undefined behavior, but given that `&argc+1` happens to be `&str` on your particular implementation, here's why you get the behavior you see on that implementation:

First let's get rid of `&argc+1` and just use `&str` instead:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc,char** argv)
{
     char *str = "Hello world";
     char *p = &str;
     printf("%i \n", &str);
     printf("%i \n",*(&str)); // (1)
     printf("%i \n", &str);
     printf("%i \n", *str); // (2)
     printf("%i \n", p);
     printf("%i \n",*p); // (3)
     return 0;
}
```

On (1) you're printing `*(&str)`, which is of course the same as `str`. This will print the memory address that is stored in the variable `str`.

On (2) you're printing `*str`. So you're taking the pointer stored in `str` and dereferencing it. The value of `*str` will be 'H' (a.k.a. 72), because that's the char that lives at the address that `str` points to.

On (3) you're printing the value that `p` points to. `p` points to `str`, so you might expect that the value of `str` would be printed just like on (1). However you declared `p` to be a `char` pointer, so dereferencing it only reads one char. So what you get instead is the first byte of `str`'s value only.

Answer (score 0):

`&argc+1` points to memory that might not be allocated to your program. This is undefined behavior, so you should not be surprised if your obeservation differs from your expectation.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is in the types of the pointers that you dereference:

- `(&argc+1)` is a pointer to `int`, dereferencing it will interprete four bytes as one integer.
- `&str` is a pointer to a pointer to a `char`, dereferencing it will interprete four/eight bytes as one pointer to a character. However, your code dereferences it twice, so when you print `*str`, you print one byte somewhere else in memory.
- `p` is a pointer to a `char`, dereferencing it will interprete just one byte as, well, one byte.

Apart from that, of course, dereferencing `(&argc+1)` does not have the blessing of the C standard, it allows the compiler to emit code that may do absolutely anything at the point where you do the dereferencing. This absolutely anything includes opening an internet connection to silently download and install a nifty little program to log your every keystroke and send it directly to the NSA or someone else... So, do try to avoid invoking undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

For one thing, these do NOT all point to the same address...what makes you think that the address of`str`is the same as`&argc+1`?  I don't think these two would be the same in ANY C compiler, on ANY platform!  But such things ARE very compiler- and platform-dependent, so to try to access memory in this way is a BAD idea, and VERY non-portable.

But setting all that aside for a moment, even if they DID point to the same address, you are USING that address in different ways in each instance... in the`(&argc+1)`case, you are printing the value of a pointer (as an integer).  In the`*(argc+1)`case, you are printing the`int`pointed-TO by that first pointer.  In the`&str`case, you are printing the ADDRESS-OF`str`(independent of the contents of`str`).  With`*str`, you are printing the`char`pointed-TO by`str`. With`p`, you are printing the value of a pointer, as with the first case`(&argc+1)`. And finally, with`*p`you are printing the`char`pointed to by the previous pointer.

Also, you are using a`%i`format to print ALL of these values, though the actual data-type of the values being printed varies... some are pointers (usually 32-bits, in most implementations), some are char's which are 8-bits.  How`printf`handles data values which do NOT align with the corresponding format strings varies by implementation, and this is BAD practice!

FYI, when I try to compile this with gcc 4.8.1 under Linux/Fedora, it gets multiple compile-time errors.

All-in-all, a LOT of ugly stuff going on here!